# To evaluate if a stochastic process $\{X_{t}\} = e^{(W_t)^4}$ where $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion is square-integrable

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I've attempted as follows

We want to know if the stochastic process is square-integrable or not by evaluting if $E[\int_{0}^{T} X_t^2] < \infty $ or no, my solution is:

$
\begin{align}
E\bigg[\int_{0}^{T} X_t^2\bigg] &= E\bigg[\int_{0}^{T} (e^{(W_t)^4})^2dt\bigg]\\
&= \int_{0}^{T} E\bigg[e^{2W_t^4}\bigg]dt\quad\text{(Fubini's Theorem)}\\
&= \int_{0}^{T}\big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{2W_t^4}e^{-\frac{Wt^2}{2t}}dW_t\big)dt\\
&= \int_{0}^{T}\big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{4tW_{t}^4 - W_{t}^2}{2t}}dW_t\big)dt\\
\end{align}
$

Then I got stuck and don't know how to proceed, can someone please point out how I can evaluate this integral?

Many thanks!

Comment: Careful. On your third line you went from integrating wrt $dt$ to integrating wrt $dW_t$

Comment: Sorry, I somehow just missed some key points in my solution there, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Please see @Snoop's answer below for a correct solution. Your current version is also unclear, as you write $\int \ldots dW_t$. Usually this means a stochastic integral, although in your case you are simply using $W_t$ as a dummy variable. This makes your attempt difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Tonelli-Fubini we can claim $E[\int_{[0,t]}X_s^2ds]=\int_{[0,t]}E[X_s^2]ds$. Then
$$E[X_t^2]=E[e^{2W_t^4}]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{2x^4-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{x^2(4tx^2-1)}{2t}}dx=\infty,\,\forall t>0$$
because for $|x|\geq M(t)$ for some $M(t)$ the exponential term shoots up to infinity as the exponentiated term becomes positive (graph it).